# Hive - Check query result against existing value set

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table like the following format.

```
product type    category    storecode
apple   F      fruit           m
tomato  v      vegetable       s
grapes  F      fruit           m
avacado v      vegetable       s
bread   b      bakery          m
```

I need to query the distinct 'type' and 'storecode' to verify that I have the result match with a predefined set of type=F,V,B,C,M and storecode=m,s. It can be in seperate queries to validate type and storecode.

I can use hive,shell,awk - Can you please suggest the best approach?

Comment: Do you want to find the rows that have incorrect type or storecode? Why is the dichotomy between hive and awk? How many rows do you have?
What have you tried?

Comment: primarily using hive and shell. Open to using awk if it can help. There are several million rows and our requirement is to make sure we have records for all type as well as storecode. So far I can query distinct records. But need an efficient way to compare the results with our predefined set of expected values. All in one query will be a preferred way. also if there are values other than the expected result(both type and storecode), that needs to be flagged too.